# Naming convention of csv file using SSIS

Tags: ssis

Am in need to generate a csv file with expression 13-MAR-2013 using SSIS..

I am able to extract date and year but struggling with month.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
(MONTH(GETDATE()) == 1 ? "Jan" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 2 ? "Feb" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 3 ? "Mar" :
MONTH(GETDATE()) == 4 ? "Apr" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 5 ? "May" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 6 ? "Jun" :
MONTH(GETDATE()) == 7 ? "Jul" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 8 ? "Aug" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 9 ? "Sep" :
MONTH(GETDATE()) == 10 ? "Oct" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 11 ? "Nov" : MONTH(GETDATE()) == 12 ? "Dec" : "InvalidMonth")
```

Comment: Glad to help, any chance of a best answer?